# Memoization: Making change with coins

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, memoization, python-decorators, coin-change

I am working on the classic *making change with coins* problem with Python. This is my implementation.

```
def memo(fn):
    def helper(*args): # here, * indicate the fn take arbitrary number of argumetns
        d = {}
        if args in d:
            return d[args] # args is a tuple, immutable, hashable
        else:
            res = fn(*args) # here * expand a tuple as arguments
            d[args] = res
            return res
    return helper

@memo
def change(options, n):
    if n < 0 or options ==():
        return 0
    elif n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return change(options, n- options[0]) + change(options[1:], n)
```

And it turns out, the memoized version is even slower than original version! Why? What is going wrong in my implementation?

This is without memoization:

```
In [172]: %timeit change((50, 25, 10, 5, 1), 100)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.12 ms per loop
```

This is with memoization:

```
In [170]: %timeit change((50, 25, 10, 5, 1), 100)
10 loops, best of 3: 21.2 ms per loop
```

Comment: You're creating a new *"cache"* dictionary **every time the decorated function is called**

Comment: The term for this technique is "memoization", not "memorization". Don't believe your spell-checker.

Comment: Thanks for correction. I always think it is memorization orz. Now I know how powerful human brain could automatically fill in illusions XD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your current code:

```
def memo(fn):
    def helper(*args):
        d = {}
```

you create a new *"cache"* dictionary `d` **every time the decorated function is called**. It's no wonder it's slower! The minimal fix is:

```
def memo(fn):
    d = {}
    def helper(*args):
```

but it could be neater generally. I use:

```
def memo(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
        if args not in wrapper.cache:
            wrapper.cache[args] = func(*args)
        return wrapper.cache[args]
    wrapper.cache = {}
    return wrapper
```

This makes it easier to access a decorated function's `cache` for bug fixing etc.

Comment: wow, so you assign a dictionary to wrapper function object as a field. This is kind of clean. Thanks !!